# C# memory / allocation cleanup

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Some near-code to try to illustrate the question, when are objects marked as available to be garbage-collected --

```
class ToyBox  
{  
    public List<Toy> Toys = new List<Toy>();  
}  
class Factory  
{  
    public ToyBox GetToys()  
    {  
        ToyBox tb = new ToyBox();  
        tb.Toys.Add(new Toy());  
        tb.Toys.Add(new Toy());

        return tb;  
    }  
}  
main()  
{  
    ToyBox tb = Factory.GetToys();  
    // After tb is used, does all the memory get cleaned up when tb goes out of scope?  
}
```

Factory.GetToys() allocates memory.  When is that memory cleaned up?  I assume that when Factoy.GetToys() returns the ToyBox object, the only reference to the ToyBox object is the one in main(), so when that reference goes out of scope, the Toy objects and the ToyBox object are marked for garbage collection.
Is that right?  Thanks for any insights...

Comment: `Factory.GetToys();` ?? that doesnt work man. you need insance of factory too.

Comment: @DarthVader He **did** say it was *near code* (aka pseudo-code)...

Comment: One cannot tell when tb will get cleaned up. Maybe sometimes in the future, after if falls out of scope, maybe never. Depends on the Garbage Collector (which is often non-deterministic).

Comment: Simon -- but tb is marked for GC when it goes out of scope, right?  That is, no explicit action need be taken to make sure there are no more references to the ToyBox object or any of the Toy objects, correct?

Answer (score 6):

> Is that right?

Yes, when the `main` method finishes executing the `tb` variable falls out of scope (unless of course you add some pointer to it to another variable which has larger scope) and `tb` is eligible for garbage collection. Of course when the actual Garbage Collection happens is out of your control. It might happen much later after the `main` method finishes executing. It's the CLR that decides the best moment. So don't be surprised if you don't reclaim all the memory allocated immediately after the `main` method finishes.

Comment: You probably meant 'eligible'.

Comment: Sorry, my English sucks like hell. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: @DarthVader, yeah I do. Luckily StackOverflow is programming related Q&A site, not like http://english.stackexchange.com/ where I would collect negative reputation :-)

Comment: +1. Please note that absolutely nothing happens at that point - GC will not immediately start collecting object. "ellegible" means just that - when/if GC will start this particluar object can be garbage collected (if it falls into currently collected generation).

Comment: Thanks, all - I wanted to confirm that nothing explicit needed to be done to clear up any references to the ToyBox object or the Toy objects...

Comment: @Number8, in a managed environment you never need to manually do anything to clean your resources except in one circumstance: if you are using unamanaged resources which are not under the control of the CLR. That's why classes dealing with unmanaged resources (database connections, file handles, ...) implement `IDisposable` so that you wrap them in `using` statements in order for this unmanaged memory to be freed as soon as you've finished using the instance, otherwise you could get a memory leak.